Align TikZ pictures horizontally
Inspired by this post I have the following code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,shapes,chains}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]
  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,3,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1.5) node[above]{};
\end{scope}

 %%%% 1.

          \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.1]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=120, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=120, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(130))^2-(1.*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(100)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(140))^2-(1.*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
    \end{scope} 
  \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
\draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:2, samples=120, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-129:193, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=194:229, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]
             \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,2.5) node[above]{};
\end{scope}


% % %%%%%% 1.4

          \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(110)} , {\t*sin(120)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(110))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(120))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(125)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(125))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \end{scope} 
 
  
\foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-107:170, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=170:250, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]

% % %%%%%% 1.6

             \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,3) node[above]{};
\end{scope}

  
          \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.3]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(140)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(100))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
            \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(130))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \end{scope} 
 
  
\foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-111:173, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    
    \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=173:244, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]

    %% 2

                 \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,5) node[above]{};
\end{scope}


          \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(130))^2-(2*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(100)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(140))^2-(2*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
    \end{scope} 
  
\foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=70, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(2*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-117:178, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    
    \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

   \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=183:243, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

   
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]

    %%%%% 3

             \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,11) node[above]{};
\end{scope}

    
          \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.6]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(140)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(100))^2-(3*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
            \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(130))^2-(3*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \end{scope} 
 
  
\foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(3*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
        \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.3*cos(\ang)} , {0.3*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.3*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.3*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.1*cos(\ang)} , {0.1*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.1*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.1*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-125:188, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    
    \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.3*cos(\ang)} , {0.3*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.3*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.3*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    
    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.1*cos(\ang)} , {0.1*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.1*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.1*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=190:235, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}

However, the different bump functions are not aligned (see below) and I would like them to be on the same (horizontal) line. I tried to play with the baseline option but did not succeed.


Not 100% perfect alignment due to the different lengths of the axis, but close: \begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth} https://i.sstatic.net/lGqbWrF9.png

use the b option to minipage. but you have overfull \hboxes you should address.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz snap!

@cfr I bet without the additional second sentence, you'd be first!

the over-fullness is due to (1) using 5 minipages each 1/5 of the \textwidth plus a positive \hspace plus spaces between the pictures due to uncommented line endings plus paragraph indentation and (2) the 'bumps' being more than 1/5 of \textwidth.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz :-)

Thanks for your quick and effective answers !

@cfr Would you like to write an answer? (I'm not really keen on adding all the % etc. in order to write one myself, but if you've already done that..)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'll post one soon !

Even without the minipages you are too wide.

@cfr Thanks for taking the time to write an answer!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz do you have any better ideas to make the content fit?

@cfr I'm wondering about using the baseline option for the tikzpictures to align them by the origin of the plots

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hmm, yes. that is probably better than current bounding box.south. but it won't eliminate the bad boxes.

Using the b option for minipage will align the plots on the baseline.
However, the content is much too wide for the page and the contents are too wide for the minipages.This may be partly due to your using a different page width in your real document, but the total width of the minipages plus space must still be too great because
(5 * 1/5 \textwidth + positive \hspace + spaces due to uncommented line endings) > \textwidth

regardless of what the value of \textwidth is.
For example, this looks OK alignment-wise:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.27\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100,baseline=(current bounding box.south)]
    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[above]{};
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,3,0) node[above]{};
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1.5) node[above]{};
    \end{scope}

    %%%% 1.

    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.1]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=120, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=120, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(130))^2-(1.*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(100)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(140))^2-(1.*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
    \end{scope}
    \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:2, samples=120, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-129:193, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=194:229, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100,baseline=(current bounding box.south)]
    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,2.5) node[above]{};
    \end{scope}

    % % %%%%%% 1.4

    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(110)} , {\t*sin(120)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(110))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(120))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(125)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(125))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \end{scope}


    \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-107:170, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=170:250, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100,baseline=(current bounding box.south)]

    % % %%%%%% 1.6

    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,3) node[above]{};
    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.3]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(140)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(100))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(130))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \end{scope}


    \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-111:173, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );


    \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=173:244, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100,baseline=(current bounding box.south)]

    %% 2

    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,5) node[above]{};
    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(130))^2-(2*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(100)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(140))^2-(2*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
    \end{scope}

    \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=70, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(2*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-117:178, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );


    \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=183:243, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.19\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100,baseline=(current bounding box.south)]

    %%%%% 3

    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
      \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,11) node[above]{};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.6]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(140)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(100))^2-(3*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(130))^2-(3*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \end{scope}

    \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(3*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.3*cos(\ang)} , {0.3*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.3*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.3*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.1*cos(\ang)} , {0.1*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.1*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.1*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-125:188, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );


    \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.3*cos(\ang)} , {0.3*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.3*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.3*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.1*cos(\ang)} , {0.1*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.1*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.1*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=190:235, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}

but the pictures overlap and compilation produces
Overfull \hbox (21.84903pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 26--27
[][]
 []


Overfull \hbox (10.47188pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 52--53
[][]
 []


Overfull \hbox (10.47166pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 89--90
[][]
 []


Overfull \hbox (10.47136pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 129--130
[][]
 []


Overfull \hbox (13.92001pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 170--171
[][]
 []


Overfull \hbox (20.69916pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--172
[][][][][]
 []

If you are actually using the default page layout, you could alter the size of the plots. It isn't good to use scale for tikzpicture, but you're already doing that, so you could just adjust it down.
Alternatively, you could lie to LaTeX and tell it the content is not as wide as it is. This can sometimes work well if you're careful.
If you are actually using a different page layout (as is typically the case), you can adjust the widths of the minipage. But a better option, in this case, is to allow the plots to take their natural width and use baseline to tikzpicture to align them. For example,
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[hscale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100,baseline=(current bounding box.south)]
  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[above]{};
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,3,0) node[above]{};
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1.5) node[above]{};
  \end{scope}

  %%%% 1.

  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.1]
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=120, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=120, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(130))^2-(1.*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(100)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(140))^2-(1.*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
  \end{scope}
  \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
  \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:2, samples=120, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-129:193, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=194:229, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100,baseline=(current bounding box.south)]
  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,2.5) node[above]{};
  \end{scope}

  % % %%%%%% 1.4

  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(110)} , {\t*sin(120)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(110))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(120))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(125)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(125))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
  \end{scope}


  \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
  \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-107:170, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=170:250, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100,baseline=(current bounding box.south)]

  % % %%%%%% 1.6

  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,3) node[above]{};
  \end{scope}


  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.3]
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(140)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(100))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(130))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
  \end{scope}


  \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
  \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-111:173, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );


  \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=173:244, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

\end{tikzpicture}%
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100,baseline=(current bounding box.south)]

  %% 2

  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,5) node[above]{};
  \end{scope}


  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5]
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(130))^2-(2*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(100)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(140))^2-(2*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
  \end{scope}

  \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
  \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=70, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(2*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-117:178, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );


  \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=183:243, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );


\end{tikzpicture}%
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100,baseline=(current bounding box.south)]

  %%%%% 3

  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
    \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,11) node[above]{};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.6]
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(140)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(100))^2-(3*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(130))^2-(3*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
  \end{scope}

  \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
  \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(3*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.3*cos(\ang)} , {0.3*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.3*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.3*sin(\ang))^2)} );
  \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.1*cos(\ang)} , {0.1*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.1*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.1*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-125:188, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );


  \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.3*cos(\ang)} , {0.3*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.3*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.3*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.1*cos(\ang)} , {0.1*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.1*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.1*sin(\ang))^2)} );

  \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=190:235, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

By using \noindent we avoid paragraph indentation. By using \hfill between plots, we ensure consistent spacing.


This solution uses \resizebox to fit as much as possible in one line.  I also used the [baseline=...] option to align the origins precisely.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,shapes,chains}
\usepackage{graphicx}% for \resizebox
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)},rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]
  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,3,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,1.5) node[above]{};
\end{scope}

 %%%% 1.

          \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.1]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=120, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=120, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(130))^2-(1.*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-2:2, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(100)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(140))^2-(1.*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
    \end{scope} 
  \foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
\draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:2, samples=120, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-129:193, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=194:229, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {2*cos(\ang)} , {2*sin(\ang)} , {1.*1.*exp(-(1.*2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.*2*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)},rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]
             \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,2.5) node[above]{};
\end{scope}


% % %%%%%% 1.4

          \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(110)} , {\t*sin(120)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(110))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(120))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(125)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(125))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \end{scope} 
 
  
\foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-107:170, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=170:250, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.4*1.4*exp(-(1.4*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.4*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)},rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]

% % %%%%%% 1.6

             \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,3) node[above]{};
\end{scope}

  
          \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.3]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(140)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(100))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
            \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(130))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \end{scope} 
 
  
\foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=-111:173, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    
    \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.2] plot[domain=173:244, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {1.6*1.6*exp(-(1.6*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(1.6*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)},rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]

    %% 2

                 \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,5) node[above]{};
\end{scope}


          \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.5]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(130))^2-(2*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(100)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(140))^2-(2*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
    \end{scope} 
  
\foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=70, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(2*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=-117:178, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    
    \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

   \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.6*cos(\ang)} , {0.6*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*0.6*cos(\ang))^2-(2*0.6*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.4] plot[domain=183:243, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {2*2*exp(-(2*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(2*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

   
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)},rotate around x=-90, rotate around z=-100]

    %%%%% 3

             \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.2]
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (-1,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,-1,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above]{};
 \draw[-{Triangle[round, width'=0pt .5, length=4pt]}] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,11) node[above]{};
\end{scope}

    
          \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.6]
      \fill[blue] plot[domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(100)} , {\t*sin(140)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(100))^2-(3*\t*sin(140))^2)} );
            \fill[blue] plot[domain=-1.4:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(130)} , {\t*sin(130)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(130))^2-(3*\t*sin(130))^2)} );
    \end{scope} 
 
  
\foreach   \ang in {-80,130}
    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=0:1.4, samples=100, variable=\t, smooth] ( {\t*cos(\ang)} , {\t*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*\t*cos(\ang))^2-(3*\t*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:110, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
        \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-45:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.3*cos(\ang)} , {0.3*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.3*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.3*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-46:120, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.1*cos(\ang)} , {0.1*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.1*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.1*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=-125:188, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    
    \draw[black,dash pattern =on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=110:270, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.2*cos(\ang)} , {0.2*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.2*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.2*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.3*cos(\ang)} , {0.3*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.3*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.3*sin(\ang))^2)} );
    
    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.4*cos(\ang)} , {0.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 1pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=140:280, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {0.1*cos(\ang)} , {0.1*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*0.1*cos(\ang))^2-(3*0.1*sin(\ang))^2)} );

    \draw[black,dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt,opacity=0.7] plot[domain=190:235, samples=100, variable=\ang, smooth] ( {1.4*cos(\ang)} , {1.4*sin(\ang)} , {3*3*exp(-(3*1.4*cos(\ang))^2-(3*1.4*sin(\ang))^2)} );
   
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\llap{\textcolor{red}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}}% show baseline

\end{document}

